# R Nested if function with NA values

Tags: r, if-statement, nested, na

I am new and self taught to R so please bear with me.

I have a variableA with 1,0 and NA values [factor type variable]. I would like to create a Variable B based on variableA values. If VariableA is 1, Variable B should be `"String 1"`, if Variable A is 0, `"String 2`", if variable A is `<NA>`, I would like to leave variable B as it is [character variable already with strings].

```
VarA    VarB
<NA>    
1   
0   
0   
0   
1   
1   
1   
0   
0   
<NA>
```

What I have tried so far hasn't worked out well. Here are two examples:

```
  if (df$VarA == 1){
    df$VarB <- "String1"
  } else if (df$VarA == 0){
      df$VarB <- "String2"
  } else{
    df$VarB <- df$VarB
  }
```

This gives an error, which I cannot spot.

The second thing I tried is the following, which turned all VarB to "String2"

```
ifelse(df$VarA == 1, df$VarB <- "StringA", df$VarB <- "String2")
```

Any help/advice/guidance on why it is not working hugely appreciated.

Comment: You might try `df$VarB[df$VarA == 1] <- "String1"` and `df$VarB[df$VarA == 0] <- "String2"`.

Comment: `df$VarB <- ifelse(df$VarA == 1, "StringA", "String2")`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to do a loop. You can also use a function.

```
#your data frame with NA, 1 and 0s
dd<-data.frame(VarA=c(NA,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,NA))
#a for loop to create the new vector in the data frame dd
for(i in 1:nrow(dd)){
#if there is an NA you will have an NA in the new vector
#here the i indicates the row we are using to get the information for the 
#new vector. It also indicates what loop we are on
  if(is.na(dd$VarA[i])){
    dd$VarB[i] <- dd$VarA[i]
#if there is a 1 in the old vector put a "String1" in the new vector
  }else if (dd$VarA[i]==1){
    dd$VarB[i] <- "String1"
#if there is a 0 in the old vector put a "String2" in the new vector
  }else if(dd$VarA[i]==0){
    dd$VarB[i] <- "String2"
#if the varible is not an NA, 1, or 0, tell me (print) that there is an error.
  }else{print("some thing is wrong")}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think Roland nailed it :)